# Density and concentration of hydroiodic acid

Tags: acid-base, concentration, reference-request, density

I weighted my hydroiodic acid sample: 25 ml weight 34.1 g, so the density is about 1.364 g/ml.

I want to know its concentration based on density. Does anyone have the corresponding density chart?

Comment: You should just titrate it.

Comment: Your right, but i just run out of indicator, have to resupply soon.

Answer (score 5):

In 1981, Nishikata et al. published [Viscosities of Aqueous Hydrochloric Acid Solutions, and Densities
and Viscosities of Aqueous Hydroiodic Acid Solutions](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/je00025a008) in the *Journal of Chemical Engineering Data*.

Table III from this paper shows what you are after.

[image: HI_density_concentration_chart]

I don't know what temperature you used to make your density measurement, but assuming it was 20 °C, then your $\ce{HI}$ looks to have a concentration of about 39 weight percent.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the density/concentration chart for aqueous $\ce{HI}$ at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\hline
\text{Density, }\pu{kg/L}(\text{@ }\pu{20 ^\circ C}) & \text{Concentration, %}(w/w) &  \text{Concentration, }(\pu{mol/L})  \\ \hline
1.0342 & 5.2 & 0.4204 \\ 
1.0812 & 10.8 & 0.9129\\ 
1.1226 & 16.4 & 1.4393 \\ 
1.1765 & 22.4 & 2.0603 \\ 
1.2333 & 27.2 & 2.6226 \\ 
1.2918 & 33.1 & 3.3429 \\ 
1.3605 & 38.7 & 4.1163\\ 
1.4208 & 42.9 & 4.7653 \\ 
1.5072 & 48.7 & 5.7385 \\ 
1.5913 & 53.0 & 6.5936 \\ 
1.6933 & 57.0 & 7.5458 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
$$

[image: HI Densities]

Evidently, the density and molarity of aqueous solutions of $\ce{HI}$ is directly proportional at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ (LHS Chart) with the equation of straight line is $y = 10.965x - 10.87$ where $x$ is density in $\pu{kg/L}$ and $y$ is the molarity ($\pu{mol/L}$). Thus,

Molarity of your $\ce{HI}$ solution is: $10.965\times 1.364 - 10.87 = \pu{4.086 mol/L}$.

I also make a plot to see how percentage of the solution behave with density. Evidently (and also agree with literature finding), the density and $w/w\%$ of aqueous solutions of $\ce{HI}$ have second order relationship at $\pu{20 ^\circ C}$ (RHS Chart) with the equation of $y = -72.044x^2 + 274.62x - 201.55$ where $x$ is density in $\pu{kg/L}$ and $y$ is the percent concentration ($w/w$). Thus,

Percent concentration of your $\ce{HI}$ solution is: $-72.044\times 1.364^2 + 274.62\times 1.364 - 201.55 = 38.99\% (w/w)$.

**Reference for densities and percentages:**

E. Nishikata, T. Ishii, T. Ohta, "Viscosities of aqueous hydrochloric acid solutions, and densities and viscosities of aqueous hydroiodic acid solutions," *J. Chem. Eng. Data* **1981**, *26(3)*, 254-256 (https://doi.org/10.1021/je00025a008).